# Hosting R output on Github

Tags: r, github, geojson

I have an R script that pulls data from our hosted DB, runs some manipulation then spits out a geojson file. I have a second script that runs the first script automatically once a week.

I want to get that final .geojson file and host it on github. However I cant figure out how to do this in the R environment. I can easily upload the code on github, but not the final output.

I am not sure if R provides this type of functionality.

Here is the code for the writing of the .geojson file

```
webmap = toGeoJSON(webmap, 'webmap_geo', "25_data", 
c("LOCATION_LONGITUDE", "LOCATION_LATITUDE"),  overwrite = TRUE)
```

The final goal is to use the data on a Mapbox GL JS map using this container javascript code

```
map.addSource('some id', {
  type: 'geojson',
  data: 'https://mydomain.mydata.geojson'
});
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use either `system` (bleh) for underlying calls to `git`, or the `git2r` package to `git2r::add`-then-`git2r::commit` changes to a local repo, then `git2r::push`.

Comment: There's also the `gh` package that goes directly to the github api. I have no experience with it, though, I don't know if it will do everything you want.